# Generate grunt task names dynamically?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a bunch of build targets based upon grunt-contrib-shell where actual target is just boiler plate which gets repeated in every target.

For example:

```
shell:
  foo_replace:
    command: 'cd ./src/foo && ./foo replace'
```

Only thing thats different between the targets is word "replace". It would make sense to avoid duplication like this and just parametrize the targetname (foo_replace) and actual parameter in command (replace).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm parsing out the structure you have going.

grunt-shell can take arguments for its commands, so potentially you could do something like

```
command: function(dir, cmd) {
  return 'cd ./src/' + dir + ' && ./' + dir + ' ' + cmd;
}
```

The task would then be run with `shell:foo:replace` either in the Gruntfile or via CLI.

Comment: The issue here is not about the actually command but the targetname which in this case is "foo_replace" as i indicated in the question w/ "parametrize the targetname (foo_replace) and actual parameter in command (replace)."